# API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I'm new to `Kotlin` development and just after I added `Kotlin` to my project there's a problem with something obsoleted. 
I saw something like this before when we had to change `compile` to `implementation`, but I really don't understand what is this about.

the warning I get:

```
API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sinamn75.androidtest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Support
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0-rc02'
    // GooglePlay
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    //AndPermission
    implementation 'com.yanzhenjie:permission:2.0.0-rc6'
    // AHNavigation
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    // Lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    // SwitchButton
    implementation 'lib.kingja.switchbutton:switchbutton:1.1.7'
    // RoundedImageView
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    // Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    // MaterialDialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.70'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task customClean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
clean.dependsOn customClean
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the `Build.gradle` file codes so we can help you easily-more? Also, `variant.getJavaCompile()` seems to be obsolete but not sure where that is to be replaced by `variant.getJavaCompileProvider()`.

Comment: thanks for answering, the problem is I ca'nt find this `variant.getJavaCompile() ` I added the gradle files @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: Can you add the IDE & Version you are using?

Comment: Android studio 3.3 canary @AbhinavSuman

Comment: the last working alpha is 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'. anything more than that, and the app will not be able to resolve the R resources

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** It seems like this is a bug in kotlin plugins which mentioned [in here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116198439)

However, using new release of kotlin plugin (When kotlin started using the new APIs) might get rid of the error as stated in here:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/1884/commits/1a17cb54a775ab3e55db66109cb12b7d54fbba6c

And: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/1884

The commit was actually for the fix of this issue:

> This commit **does not change anything functionally**, **it is only to avoid
>   the warning message**, as reporter in
>   https://issuetracker.google.com/116198439

---

After a deep search into codes, seems like [**`getJavaCompile()`**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/api/BaseVariant.java#177) is obsolete in your current gradle (`alpha11` version). However, you were using **alpha** version of `gradle` which I don't really recommend that.

Instead, try using the stable versions like:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

And then warning should be gone I hope.

Comment: Even though this will get rid of the warning for now, this is not a solution. If the op wants to use the Canary version of Android Studio, why not? The thing is, it's a warning, not caused by anything the op wrote. It can be safely ignored, as it will be fixed way before the end of 2019, without the op doing anything.

Comment: Absolutely, that's just **a warning** however. Since the OP was concerned about this issue, I think I've explained everything and using the stable version of `gradle` should help (for now).

Comment: it not correct answer, not every user always on same version... if just warning then it has solution

Comment: @Lokesh Updated the answer. Thanks for mentioning BTW.

Answer (score 6):

This warning is related to the Kotlin plugins still using the older (deprecated) APIs.

Please check the below issue on Google issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116198439

Duplicate issue with some more info:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116148147

It will be fixed when Kotlin plugin will start using the newer APIs. Please check the issues here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25428
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/1884

Answer (score 1):

If used to google crashlytics

Please do upgrade your gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // Change classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0' to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```